# React: Why is the debugger pausing twice, but console.log logging once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, create-react-app, vscode-debugger

My create-react-app project component:

```js
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  console.log('rendered');
  debugger;
  return <div>hi</div>;
}

export default App;
```

I'm using VSCode with these launch configurations:

```json
{
   "type": "chrome",
   "request": "launch",
   "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
   "url": "http://localhost:3000",
   "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/frontend-react"
},
```

When I refresh the page **debugger pauses twice**, so the program is hitting `console.log('rendered');` twice. But in the console, ***"rendered"* is only logged once**.

1. Why isn't *"rendered"* logging twice?
2. Why is the program running twice?

Comment: Thanks, I tested this and changed `ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode><App /</React.StrictMode>,document.getElementById('root')
);`  in `index.js` to `ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));` and it now only renders once so this part is correct and answers my 2nd question. But for my first question- the poster of the question you linked to said that their logs were logged twice when the script ran twice. I wonder why mine logged once?

Comment: Are you sure it didn't log twice? Most browsers will indicate multiple identical messages by putting the count beside them instead of actually printing the message twice.

Comment: yea I know what you mean. I was looking for that too, but no it didn't happen. Anyways you mostly answered my problem because I just I didn't want a bunch of waisted renders. I'm not sure why it didn't log twice but it seems related to this strict mode too.